# Commuting endomorphisms (Binomial theorem)

Tags: binomial-theorem

If $f$, $g$ $\in End(V)$  are commuting, then it's:

$(f+g)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix}}f^{n-k}\circ  g^k$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$

I tried to compute it with the binomial theorem but i didn't get the result. How can it be done?

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: Since these endomorphisms are commuting: $(f+g)^n=(g+f)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix}}g^{n-k}\circ f^k$ and that's not the same as the result.

Comment: @Humertun Yes it is the same. You might note that your argument would show that the binomial theorem is false for _numbers_...

Comment: The binomial theorem says that if $a$ and $b$ are scalars then $(a+b)^n$ equals a certain sum. Since $f$ and $g$ are not scalars I don't see how it's possible to "compute" this using the binomial theorem - it simply doesn't apply. _But_  you can use the _proof_ of the standard binomial theorem, by induction on $n$...

Comment: Note that $f,g$ commuting means $fg=gf$ in this case,  i.e. they commute with respect to composition. Knowing this, you should be able to generalize the proof of the binomial theorem in order to include this particular situation.